# Threadpool Executor still blocks in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool

I am trying to make sure that I understand how to do non-blocking I/O in Python correctly.  In looking at example from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/concurrency_in_python/concurrency_in_python_pool_of_threads.htm) I am still a little confused:

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request

URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
   'http://www.cnn.com/',
   'http://europe.wsj.com/',
   'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
   'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

def load_url(url, timeout):
   with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout = timeout) as conn:
   return conn.read()

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 5) as executor:
   future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
   for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
       url = future_to_url[future]
       try:
          data = future.result()
       except Exception as exc:
          print('%r generated an exception: %s' % (url, exc))
       else:
          print('%r page is %d bytes' % (url, len(data)))
```

This block of code downloads the URLs in parallel, but let's say I have something that needs updates without blocking (like printing a status update every .2 seconds.

Where does that code go?

It seems like even though the URL downloads are not blocking each other, the overall task of downloading all the URLs is blocking the rest of the program while they complete downloading.

Comment: threads are not always the answer for non-blocking I/O: it is in fact executing blocking I/O in a OS-level construct, that is scheduled by the system. Go for real non-blocking I/O: have a look at asyncio or (better): [gevent](http://gevent.org)

Comment: I looked at `asyncio` but it seemed to have the same problem.  The `run_forever` loop still blocks.

Comment: But that's what every thread in every program does: it runs until it blocks, or exits, or enters a loop.  If you want to print a status message every 0.2s, write some code in a loop that does that and execute it in a thread.  If the thread isn't a daemon it will run forever. A Python program exits when all its non-daemon threads are finished.  That's all there is to it.  There is no magic.